# Sticky section in particular view port

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport, sticky

For example my document height is 4100, I need to show a section within the height of 500 to 3600. I've tried my best with the below code. I didn't get the proper output. Kindly share your thoughts.

```
var start = $(document).scrollTop();
var stop = $(document).height() - 500;
$('#onScrollShow').hide();
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (start < stop) {
      $('#onScrollShow').show();
  } else {
      $('#onScrollShow').hide();
  }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="onScrollShow"> some text </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the position of the page *inside* your scroll event, so jQuery will check the value every time a user scrolls:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); //gets value every scroll
    if (scroll < stop) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used your code with my conditions and it works!

Answer (score 0):

This is working!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if ((currentScroll > 400) && (currentScroll < 2500)) {
        $('#onScrollShow').slideDown();
    }else {
            $('#onScrollShow').slideUp();
        }
});
```